# save an imageview in specified place in android studio

Tags: android

I am developing an android application in which i am doing some editing on the image from imageview as writing something or add an icon. so i want to save that image after editing in a specified location on a button click.
how can i achieve this?
please help me.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mvieww"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:id="@+id/etext"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You can create a new bitmap and then save it to the sd-card. I don't know exactly how to do this. Maybe you can find something useful in the [Bitmap doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)

Comment: thanks..........................

Comment: Are you even trying or is this just a challenge to create a lot of questions ?

Comment: it is part of my android application